# Converting .ifc files to .glb format and parsing .ifc files into Java objects in Java

Tags: java, ifc

I'm working on a Java project where I need to handle .ifc (Industry Foundation Classes) files. I have two specific requirements:

Conversion: I need to convert .ifc files into .glb (GLTF Binary) format. Are there any Java libraries or tools available that can help with this conversion process?

Parsing: Once I have an .ifc file, I need to parse its contents and extract relevant information into Java objects for further processing. Are there any Java libraries specifically designed for parsing .ifc files and generating Java objects from them?

I've done some research but haven't found a straightforward solution yet. Any recommendations or insights into available libraries or tools that can assist with these tasks would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Most likely you'll have to break the problem up into smaller pieces. `I've done some research` What have you found so far? Could you use it to attempt a solution?